# how to remove select a value from drop down in SSRS report parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, report

how to remove  from drop down in SSRS report parameter? if i set default value to report parameters,  gets disappear in preview but it will appears after deploy the reposts

Comment: If you have set new parameter defaults in Visual Studio, they may not get deployed to Report Manager. You can either go to the report properties in Report Manager and change the parameter defaults manually to match those in Visual Studio, or delete and re-deploy the report (note that deleting the report in Report Manager will lose any subscriptions to the report).

Answer (score 1):

Using a default value will remove the 'select a value' option from the list. This default can be different from values in the list and is set from the bottom section of the parameters menu.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly:  just create a separate data set and use the result set as the available values for your parameter.  Discriminate in your where clause.

```
-- (example) Query used in the CarMakes dataset
SELECT DISTINCT make
FROM    tbl_Cars
where  make not like 'Toyota',
        and make not like 'Ford'
        and make not like 'Kia'
union select '- Select Make -';  -- used as first value in drop down
```

Then set the data set you create as the available values for your parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In the Report Manager click by the side of the report to bring on the other options. Click on Manage. In the report properties, click on Parameters. Set the default value for what ever parameter you were doing in the BIDS. VOILA...

I faced the same issue. Tried this method and got it.

Cheers!!!

Vihar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The only thing that helped me was in parameter properties in default value to input the value like expression (**don't just enter value in textbox**)

Try to build expression: =your_value

example: =1

Answer (score 0):

**To remove the default values for a report parameter**

```
In the Report Data pane, expand the **Parameters** node. Right-click the parameter and click **Edit**. The **Report Parameter Properties** dialog box opens.

Click **Default Values**.

**In Select from one of the following options**, click **No default value.**

Click OK.
```

Answer (score 0):

If your drop-down result set has values like the below:

```
**id-value**

 - 1--ABC 
 - 2--XYZ 
 - 3--SWS
```

Just add the `null,'-Select-'` value to the top of the result set:

```
**id-value**

 - null-- -Select- 
 - 1--ABC
 - 2--XYZ
 - 3--SWS
```

Now go to your report's parameter properties and set a default value `(null)`.

**Note:** Default value should be in brackets: `(null)`